# SQL IF same then ADD

Tags: mysql, if-statement, addition

What I am trying to do is, find a particular string in `Table1.xxx`, if it matches then it takes the figure in nnn and mmm and adds it to the matching `uid` in 'Table2' then deletes that record.

```
Table1
|   uid |   xxx |   nnn |   mmm |
---------------------------------
|   100 |   abc |   111 |   222 |
|   121 |   def |   144 |   244 |
|   100 |   ghi |   411 |   844 |
```

Table2

```
|   uid |   nnn |   mmm |
 -----------------------
|   100 |   644 |   441 |
```

Comment: Do you have a query that you've been working on that we can take a look at? Please show where you are in the process of figuring this out so that we can help you get past where you are stuck.

Comment: You can't update and delete at the same time.

Comment: This should be a simple `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`.

Comment: Make a concrete example based on your data please.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question? This site is for programming questions. it's not a place to dump your to-do lists.

Comment: I haven't started working on any queries yet, I'm a newbie to SQL, so I can do simple select, update, insert queries. With this one, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Barmar

Comment: Marc B - I'm not dumping my to-do list on anyone, I thought this site was for help, hence I asked for a heads up.

Comment: Help = You make an attempt, if you can't get it to work you post what you tried, we help you fix it. Help != we do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`

```
UPDATE table2 AS t2
JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.uid = t2.uid
SET t2.nnn = t2.nnn + t1.nnn, t2.mmm = t2.mmm + t1.mmm
```

To delete the record from table 1:

```
DELETE t1 FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.uid = t2.uid
```

You should do these in a transaction to ensure that the `DELETE` query only deletes the rows that were used in the earlier `UPDATE`.